# Form inherits color from body. Help appreciated

Tags: html, css, forms, colors, background-color

I am super newb in terms of CSS, and I can't understand why my form is having issues with the colors. I wrapped a form inside a div, but still I can see background color from a body.
I tried everything, including coloring every single div separately. It is not a good practice, and not everything was coloured anyways, so I need a better solution.
Could you help me sort the colors out? Thank you so much.

Code below:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: lightblue;
}

#upper-text {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.form_style {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: white;
}

#container {
  display: block;
  height: 450px;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px grey;
  background-color: white;
}

#form_wrap {
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}

#space {
  margin-bottom: 10em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js.js"></script>
  <title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="space"></div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="upper-text">
      <h1>I dare you to Sign Up</h1>
      <p>It's free * </p>
    </div>
    <div id="form_wrap">
      <div class="form_style">
        <label>First Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Filip">
      </div>
      <div class="form_style">
        <label>Last Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nakrętka">
      </div>
      <div class="form_style">
        <label>Email</label><br>
        <input type="email" placeholder="filipnak@piesek.pl">
      </div>
      <div class="form_style">
        <label>Email Again</label><br>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="confemail" placeholder="filipnak@piesek.pl">
      </div>
      <div class="form_style">
        <label>Password</label><br>
        <input name="password" type="text" id="pass">
      </div>
      <div class="form_style">
        <div id="btn">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because you apply `color: lightblue;` for all element, including form.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand it now :) 

For other people as silly as myself: add color to body, not to *